# UiButton inside or outside Uitableviewcell

Tags: uitableview

I am working on an iOS app login screen like Facebook.
Everything works fine I used prototype cells for the username and password however I would like your advice regarding the login button.

I added a 2nd section in the uitablevjew to hold  the button. I was able to connect the action but if i am not wrong by looking at the facebook app button they have a backgroound image that perfectly fits the cell.
What is the difference between this approach and just placing an image outside? Did they do it that way to move the cell easily when editing starts?

Please advise

Comment: Do you have a link to an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I will add it but it is basically the same login screen that you see in Facebook iOS app. Thanks